# Как вынести SQL-запрос из цикла?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Можно ли как-нибудь вынести запрос из цикла? То есть нужно, чтобы выборка по всем `tag_id` выполнилась одним запросом. И как потом этот результат передать в существующий цикл, чтобы поведение сохранилось?

```
foreach ($rows as $i=>$row)
{
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article_tags WHERE tag_id = '$row['id']'"));
    if (count($result) > 0)
        $status = 1;
    else
        $status = 0;
    $responce->rows[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell'] = array("", $row['id'], $row['name'], $row['alias'], $status);
}
```

Comment: запрос в начале делаем допустим `'SELECT * FROM article_tags WHERE tag_id IN ('. implode(',', $rows).')'`  а потом по результату циклом бежим... вообще зависит от того, что в базе и какую задачу решаете.... может и не `IN` нужен, а подзапрос...Но одним запросом в данном случае очевидно, что можно решить задачу.

Comment: В бд 200к записей. Поэтому нужен наиболее экономичный способ

Comment: И вы прям все 200к за раз тащите? если да - зачем? И еще вопрос... чтобы в $rows  оказались айдишники вы запрос какой-нибудь делали? Какой? Что там есть еще сверху?

Comment: Все 200к за раз, тк генерится таблица со всеми тегами. А в $rows непосредственно результат выборки из таблицы тегов

Comment: `Поэтому нужен наиболее экономичный способ` - так я вам и предлагаю один запрос вне цикла сделать с использованием IN. Это явно экономнее, чем цикл... или в чем заключается нееокномичность IN? Скажите пожалуйста.... (`SELECT * FROM article_tags WHERE tag_id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE /* условие */)`)... 200к за раз вам не нужно. вы что сразу всю таблицу выплюнете юзеру? да у него браузер зависнет... данные в любом случае предоставляются по частям

Comment: Так через IN выбирает только те записи, tag_id которых у нас есть. А в моем случае, если tag_id не нашло, то возвращался пустой массив. Как мне тогда узнать в какой из итераций $count будет равна нулю?

Comment: сделайте временную таблицу с нужными id и left joiт

Comment: как минимум `SELECT at.*, IF(ISNULL(at.id), 0, 1) AS status
FROM article_tags at
RIGHT JOIN tags t
ON at.tags_id = t.id`  и будет вам сразу таблица со столбцом статуса..Даже вместо 0/1 можете написать выполнено/невыполнено ...... хотя тоже не оптимальный вариант....но что-то в эту сторону надо покопать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article_tags"));
foreach ($rows as $i=>$row) {
    if (in_array($row['id'], $result))
        $status = 1;
    else
        $status = 0;
    $responce->rows[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell'] = array("", $row['id'], $row['name'], $row['alias'], $status);
}
```

Сделайте запрос, а потом в цикле проверяйте есть ли нужное значение в массиве результата запроса.

Comment: Так в этом случае нужно же еще перебор `$result` делать, внутри которого будет `if (in_array(....))`. А это будет еще круче сервер нагружать

Comment: Тогда Вам нужно делать 1 запрос к таблице из которой Вы получаете массив $rows и левым соединением (LEFT JOIN ON (название первой таблицы.tag_id =  article_tags.tag_id) получать данные из таблицы "article_tags".

Comment: Например есть таблица table и article_tags. Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так: "SELECT t.*, at.tag_id FROM article_tags at LEFT JOIN table t ON (t.id = at.tag_id)" И если нужно можете добавить свои условия "WHERE t.id = ", или другие. Таким образом Вы получите массив в котором значения  по ключу "tag_id" будут NULL если по id из первой таблицы ничего не найдено во второй